# Where to find the lib folder for wicket installation?

Tags: linux, wicket

I am installing the Wicket framework for my web application on eclipse-Juno.I am not able to find the lib folder wherein i have to put some supporting jar files.Here is the list of folders i have after unzipping my downloaded wicket:archetypes,licenses,testing,wicket,wicket-spring etc.am i installing correctly or have i downloaded the wrong wicket?Please help

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're struggling with "installing" Wicket into Eclipse and unzipping some distributions, you should definitely look into [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/), [Gradle](http://gradle.org/) or any other tool that helps you to manage your dependencies.

However, if you're really, really, really struggling with this, I suggest that you start learning some more about the Java classpath, what IDEs do and what they don't do and how libraries are usually distributed in the Java world before actually tackling a Wicket project. Believe me, you will benefit from the knowledge you gain here throughout your life as a developer.

Answer (score 1):

Your Web application project should have a `lib` directory, where you place all libraries (jar files) used in your web application. This is not specific to Eclipse, Wicket and Linux. Then you should [add](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29) jars to to a build path in Eclipse.